# Denormalizing relational data for lucene/solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have an architectural question about using apache solr/lucene.

I'm building a solr index for searching a CV database. Basically every cv on there will have some fields like:

rate of pay, address, title

these fields are straight forward. The area I need advise on is, skills and job history. 
For skills, someone might add an entry like: C# - 5 Years, Java - 9 Years

So there's essentially N number of skills, each with a string name and a int no of years. 
I was thinking I could use a dynamic field, *_skill, and possibly add them like so:

1_skill: C#, 2_skill: Java

But how can I index the years experience? would I then add a dynamic field like:

1_skill_years: 5, 2_skill_years: 9

Has anyone done similar things before?
Any help greatly appreciated?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Multi-valued fields maintain ordering so you could have a multi-valued field for skills and another one for years of experience. When you read them back, just associate them by their order.

Pay attention if you have a null or empty value. You will have to encode it using a special marker because en empty string or a null value will not be indexed and this will change the ordering.

**UPDATE**
Unfortunately, it is not possible in Solr to sort by a multi-valued field. See this link for explanations: 
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/performance-sorting-multivalued-field-td905943.html

Comment: how would i sort a query based on the value in another field. 

i.e. java 5 years experience
if 
skill:       java (index 2) 
skill_years: 5 (index 2) 

is it possible for me to sort, facet on these values when they're stored like this?

Comment: No, Solr can't sort on multi-valued field.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a dynamic field, you could use multi-valued fields. You do know that the multiple values can exist for the same field. Hence something like

```
<Skill> Java
<Skill> Solr
```

etc.

Comment: yes i'm familiar with MVF's and it would be perfect if it was just the name of the skill, but the issue is how do i then include the number of years experience. 


i.e. if i'm going to search for Java with 5 Years experience it needs to be captured in 2 different fields. 

ultimately I'd like to be able to facet and sort on the number of years someone has a skill also.

Comment: @mickdelaney, did you get any solution for your skill with year problem?